# SharePoint 2013 foundation limitations

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-foundation, enterprise-search

One of our clients asked about SharePoint foundation server 2013 capabilities, and why he cannot use it . So I have read this link regarding the main differences between SharePoint Foundation & SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise http://www.apps4rent.com/sharepoint-2013-features-comparison.html.
So can I generally conclude that SP 2013 Foundation does **NOT** have the following:-

1. Search Manage Service Applications.
2. Web Content Management , including the out of the box approval workflow.
3. Th ability for the users to create their own sites (my sites)
4. The user profile Manage Service Applications.
5. Mobile and Device Rendering

Comment: If this is a 100+ company you would also point out that they will need to upgrade in the near future. Why would they need to upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well...
The list is quite extensive when you look at it flat foundation vs enterprise. And not knowing what your customers needs are I would, personally, tell these things to my customer;

- Custom site definitions and site provisioning are not available.
- InfoPath forms service
- Access Services
- Workflows
- Documents Sets
- Managed Metadata
- Document IDs

And ALL of the BI goodies are missing.

If this is a 100+ company you would also point out that they will need to upgrade in the near future. And that is a costly operation if the Sharepoint server is classified as a "A" system.

If they know that they just need a place to keep some documents somewhere with versioning, just let them have the foundation one and move on to new lands of bigger Sharepoint adventures :)

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually our client wants to build a public website with content management system and some built-in workflows. so will the foundation version satisfy his needs ? or the SP foundation 2013 does not support content managment and does not have a built-in workflow ?

Comment: Foundation does not support Publishing.

Comment: All of the sexy wcm features are missing in the foundation version and just some are present in the standard version. No workflows either.

Comment: Foundation supports Workflows (but not the newer Workflow Management-based workflows).